# Python numpy savetxt not saving: "tuple index out of range"

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I wrote the following python code that (supposedly) extracts data from a FITS file.

```
target_array=np.loadtxt(target_list)
N=len(target_array)
target=['target_{0}.fits'.format(i) for i in range(1,N+1,1)]
hdu=[]
hdudata=[]
for i in range(N):
hdu.append(pyfits.open(target[i]))
hdudata.append(hdu[i][1].data)
f=[]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(len(hdudata[i])):
        if dist(target_array[i][0],hdudata[i][j]['Ra'],target_array[i][1],hdudata[i][j]['Dec']) <= func(hdudata[i][j]['Energy']):
                            f.append(hdudata[i][j]['Energy'])
        print "Target", i, "successfully stacked"

np.savetxt('energy_stack.txt',f)
```

target_array is a N x 2 array containing the coordinates for the target of interest. Each target FITS file contains thousands of 'events' that are linked to a specific coordinates and energy. The code cycles through each event in each target and grabs the energy for events that meet a criteria (the distance between the the target coordinates and the event coordinates must be less then some specified number), if it meets the criteria it is saved to "f" which is a 1D array, a simple list of numbers (about 23000 numbers).

Everything works up until the savetxt command and then it spits the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipe_stack.py", line 184, in <module>
    get_target_energy('target_list_reduced.txt')
  File "pipe_stack.py", line 132, in get_target_energy
    np.savetxt('energy_stack.txt',f)
  File "/home/heatdeath/fermi_science/ScienceTools-v10r0p5-fssc-20150518A-source/external/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-libc2.19-0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1118, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I need to know what is going wrong. This code worked for a different sample.

Comment: Don't worry about the function, func(), it is built from interp1D and works fine

Comment: It seems that `f` which you are saving in `savetxt` contains only 1 or less items. So the if cases in the for loop are not true as often as they should be. This seems to be the line where numpy fails: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1118

Comment: What's the data structure of `f`? Judging from the code you provided `f=[]` makes f a list. According to [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), the second parameter of `np.savetxt` function - `X` needs to be "array_like"

Answer (score 0):

The first thing `savetxt` does with your `f` (called `X`) is

```
X = np.asarray(X)
```

This, it makes it into an array. `savetxt` is designed to write a 2d array for numbers, one row at a time to the file.

As you create it, `f=[]`, and then you `f.append...`.  So it's a list of somethings - lists, arrays?

You need to look at `f` and figure out how to turn it into a valid numpy array.

Comment: I create an empty list and then append that list with floating point numbers. At the end of the code, the list "f" should be of the form: f=[50.02,43.21,78.91.....] as an example and contains about 23,000 of these floating point numbers. If you say the first thing that savetxt does is turn it into an array, I don't understand why it cant turn this list of numbers into an array and save it. 
Should I maybe use: f=np.array(f) ?

Comment: Do `arr=np.array(f)`, and tell us about `arr.shape` and `arr.dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Instead of appending an empty array I made an extremely large, two dimensional one:

```
f=np.zeros((N,1e6))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(len(hdudata[i])):
        if dist(target_array[i][0],hdudata[i][j]['Ra'],target_array[i][1],hdudata[i][j]['Dec']) <= func(hdudata[i][j]['Energy']):
            f[i][j]=hdudata[i][j]['Energy']
    print "Target", i, "successfully stacked"
```

I hoped by initializing the array that it would save time as the computer wouldn't have to go back and forth allocating memory every time it appended the array. (In theory it works faster but in my experience it seemed the same). Anyway, I then used some numpy tricks to flatten the 2D array into a 1D array, and then I deleted the extra zeros with the following code:

```
f=np.ndarray.flatten(f)
f=f[f!=0]
np.savetxt('energy_stack.txt',f)
```

Then the savetxt worked. I don't know why it didnt work with the previous method because I was saving a 1D array filled with floats, and thats exactly what I am doing here I just reworked it to save time (supposedly). Anyway. Thanks all for your help.